# Getting rid of TypeError while initializing HandsOntable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am checking [Handsontable for developers](https://handsontable.com/) for one of my project. I have tried to initialize a handsontable object by following their tutorial. But i am continuously getting a **TypeError**.

My code is below -

```js
var data = [
   ["","Ford","Volvo","Toyota","Honda"],
   ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
   ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
   ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var container = $("#example");
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
   data: data,
   rowHeaders: true,
   colHeaders: true
});
```

```html
<link href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.25.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.25.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/x1w95ndx/

I have been trying to find the solution for last one hour. It will be really helpful for me if anyone show me the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are passing a [jQuery collection](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) (an array-like object which can contain multiple elements and offers those jQuery methods like `.css` and `.attr`) to the `Handsontable` constructor, when it expects a plain DOM element.

Replace:

```
var container = $("#example");
```

With:

```
var container = $("#example")[0];
```

Or:

```
var container = document.getElementById("example");
```

### Working Example:

```js
var data = [
   ["","Ford","Volvo","Toyota","Honda"],
   ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
   ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
   ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var container = $("#example")[0];
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
   data: data,
   rowHeaders: true,
   colHeaders: true
});
```

```html
<link href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.25.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.25.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks my problem is solved. I just have a question. Can you please explain this code - $("#example")[0]; Is jquery saving the DOM in an array ?

Comment: @ni8mr It's an array-like object which can contain multiple elements and exposes the methods like `.css` and `.attr`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you provide me with an article related to it. (I know i am asking much. But this seems interesting to me. I am new to JS and jquery. )

Comment: @ni8mr Here's some basic info on the object: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/ Unfortunately, I'm not coming up with a really technical writeup.

Comment: Ok. That link is enough. :)